# How do I install Ubuntu on a Debian PC?

Tags: system-installation

After Windows closed Windows XP I installed Linux-Debian on my PC and it's not completely what I wanted. So a friend of mine told me to change to Ubuntu.

I already burned it on a CD and tried to open it in the boot menu but that won't work if you haven't run the .exe file in the downloaded package. But I haven't installed the program(s) to run .exe files.

Is there something I can do to run the .exe file or is there a version of Ubuntu that can be installed from Debian?

I'm new to the Linux software, so I really don't know where to look for the right software.

Comment: How did you burn the ISO to the CD? You don't have to run the `.exe` file.

Comment: How to install --> http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

You say: I already burned it on a CD , so you have already downloaded a .iso file from [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Now you select at BIOS as first boot device your cdrom and restart your computer.

The last step is put your CD at the cdrom and select install Ubuntu from the CD menu.

The .exe are executable files for Microsoft Windows, so you do not need a .exe file for installation.

--

Help from ubuntu.com for installing from CD or DVD, click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD)

( Just ignore the steps for windows )

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you boot your machine with the linux CD on and it'll boot the install sequence? Please make sure you have all your data backed up AND that you have space on your disk to install Ubuntu (if you're not going to overwrite Debian). Make sure to taste many flavours of linux (such as, say, Xubuntu as well).
Another safe way to test it would be using a virtual machine (since you'll be able to do so without damaging your system at all).